# Javascript - Different values getting for Math.pow(Math.E, 3) and Math.exp(3)

Tags: javascript

I tried `Math.pow()` and `Math.E` and I found this difference in values. I don't know how the results are different?

```
Math.pow(Math.E, 3) => 20.085536923187664
Math.exp(3) => 20.085536923187668
```

I am doing wrong thing or what, I can't understand.

Comment: You can't represent _e_ perfectly on a computer. Doing `Math.exp` most likely gives you a value closer to the truth. `Math.pow` probably has growing error for each higher value. `Math.E` isn't really _e_, it's just a good estimate.

Comment: This might help- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374763/which-is-more-accurate-java-lang-math-e-or-math-exp1-0

Comment: I tried a calculator app and got the first answer.